# Sql Server- Get the dates from the database between the range supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue to get the records if the FtableID at any point in the range (Start date and End date) has a StatusID=2.

> My table Structure is

`ID    FTableID  StatusID    AddedOn
75324   53591    1          2019-03-17 06:48:14.490
75325   53591    2          2019-03-18 06:48:14.663
75326   53591    3          2019-03-19 06:54:20.830`

```
@StartDate Datetime='2019/03/17 23:00:00' ,            
@EndDate Datetime='2019/03/20 23:59:59' 

Select ID, FTableID,StatusID,AddedOn from MyTableName where FTableID=53591
And StatusID=2 and AddedOn <= @EndDate
```

I know my query is wrong and it gives the record even when I pass the @startdate after its status gets changed to **3** (**Completed**)

> I am confused to set the start date filter.

I need to check if this FtableID record is in status id =2 at any point in the range supplied

The record should come If I pass the  @StartDate Datetime='2019/03/18 23:00:00', @EndDate Datetime='2019/03/20 23:59:59' because it is in this range it was in the status=2

The record should not come If I pass the  @StartDate Datetime='2019/03/19 23:00:00', @EndDate Datetime='2019/03/20 23:59:59' because it was convertted to statusID=3

Please suggest me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhm, so if you have that `@StartDate` variable, then why not use it in the SQL? I.e.  `and AddedOn >= @StartDate` Or is the problem that the `@StartDate` is after that datetime of status 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
select * 
from YourTableName
where AddedOn between (@StartDate and @EndDate)
and StatusID=2
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `exists`.

I would simplify your date arithmetic as well, so:

declare @StartDate datetime '2019-03-17 23:00:00';
declare @EndDate datetime = '2019-03-20'

```
select t.*
from mytablename t
where exists (select 1
              from mytablename t2
              where t2.ftableid = t.ftableid and
                    t2.statusid = 2 and
                    t2.AddedOn >= @StartDate and
                    t2.AddedOn < @EndDate 
             );
```